# How to find the smallest number from a given set of numbers?

Tags: macros, conditionals, datatool

Is there any package or macro that implements getting the smallest number from a given row of numbers? using ifthen package.

I was not able to get it. Here is my MWE.

```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage{datatool}
  \usepackage{ifthen,fp}
  \begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
      Name, EL-1,   EL-2,   EL-3,   EL-4
      Biki,  60,      40,     50,    80
  \end{filecontents*}
  \DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}
  \begin{document}
  \DTLforeach{data}{\a=EL-1,\b=EL-2,\c=EL-3,\d=EL-4}{

  \ifthenelse{\a<\b}{
        \ifthenelse{\b<\c}{
                     \ifthenelse{\c<\d}{
                      The smallest number is \a
                                       }{}  
                          }{}
              }{}
   \ifthenelse{\b<\a}{
        \ifthenelse{\a<\c}{
                     \ifthenelse{\c<\d}{
                      The smallest number is \b
                                       }{}  
                          }{}
              }{}           
    \ifthenelse{\c<\a}{
        \ifthenelse{\a<\b}{
                     \ifthenelse{\b<\d}{
                      The smallest number is \c
                                       }{}  
                          }{}
              }{}
    \ifthenelse{\d<\a}{
        \ifthenelse{\a<\b}{
                     \ifthenelse{\b<\c}{
                      The smallest number is \d
                                       }{}  
                          }{}
              }{}                  

  }
  \end{document}
```

Comment: What's your aim? Read a csv file and get the smallest number of all? Get the smallest number in each row/column?

Comment: Get the smallest number from a given set of columns@TeXnician

Comment: In a row or on the whole?

Comment: I have modified the database for understanding, here i have number as 60,40,50, 80 in a row file should be read from .csv so i want to get the smallest number@TeXnician

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Name,         EL-1, EL-2, EL-3, EL-4
Biki,           60,   40,   50,   80
Don Giovanni,  640,  231,  100,   91
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xparse,xfp}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\minimum}{m}{%
  \fpeval{min(#1)}%
}

\DTLloaddb{data}{\jobname.csv}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{data}{\a=EL-1,\b=EL-2,\c=EL-3,\d=EL-4,\n=Name}{%
  The smallest number for \n\ is \minimum{\a,\b,\c,\d}\par
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A (nonexpandable) version with standard integer comparison:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Name,         EL-1, EL-2, EL-3, EL-4
Biki,           60,   40,   50,   80
Don Giovanni,  640,  231,  100,   91
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\minimum}[1]{%
  \def\biki@found{\maxdimen}%
  \@for\next:=#1\do{%
    \biki@minimum{\biki@found}{\next}%
  }
  \biki@found
}
\newcommand{\biki@minimum}[2]{%
  \ifnum#2<#1\relax
    \edef\biki@found{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\DTLloaddb{data}{\jobname.csv}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{data}{\a=EL-1,\b=EL-2,\c=EL-3,\d=EL-4,\n=Name}{%
  The smallest number for \n\ is \minimum{\a,\b,\c,\d}\par
}

\end{document}
```

The recursion starts by comparing the largest integer `\maxdimen` with the first item in the list; at each step, if the next integer in the list is less than the stored one, the item is stored in `\biki@found`. Finally, `\biki@found` is delivered.

Comment: Not working for other sets of integer@egreg

Comment: @BikiTeron *What* other sets of integers? I can only work with the one you provided. The macro will print the smallest number in each row. If you want to find the smallest number in *each column*, then you should provide a more meaningful example and be more precise about your aim.

Comment: @egreg See the comments below my answer, probably the same issue with not deleting the filecontents file.

Answer (score 4):

The following code will print the smallest number in a row:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{datatool,expl3}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Name, EL-1,   EL-2,   EL-3,   EL-4
Biki,  60,      40,     50,    80
\end{filecontents*}
\DTLloaddb{data}{data.csv}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DTLforeach{data}{\a=EL-1,\b=EL-2,\c=EL-3,\d=EL-4}{
    \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist { \a, \b, \c, \d }
    \clist_sort:Nn \l_tmpa_clist
        {
            \int_compare:nNnTF { #1 } > { #2 }
                { \sort_return_swapped: }
                { \sort_return_same: }
        }
    \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { 1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now working for other sets@TeXnician

Comment: @BikiTeron What do you mean? Your set shall only contain integers, otherwise you would have to replace `\int_compare` by `\fp_compare`. But as you did not provide examples it is hard to guess your data.

Comment: data is only integer but number may any numbers@TeXnician

Comment: @BikiTeron To me it is not clear what you mean with numbers. For what I see your data consists of numbers, but they are all integers and there my code is working. If you have other "numbers" (i.e. floats) you need to replace int with fp as I said.

Comment: when i change the value of EL-3 as 10 smallest value still showing as 40@TeXnician

Comment: @BikiTeron But you really change the file and not the values in the filecontents envrionment, don't you? The filecontents environment works only once. If the file (with the old data) exists you will not see any change.

Comment: I am sorry, i did'nt remove the old .csv file thats why it is showing only 40, now it is working Thank you so much@TeXnician

Comment: can we implement using ifthen package@TeXnician

Comment: @BikiTeron I am not experienced with ifthen. Maybe someone else.